# jQuery event mousedown always return root

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I bind event like this:

```
Selector.prototype.setupEventHandlers = function() {
    var cssSelector = '*:not(.' + this.ignoreClass + ')';
    jQuery(cssSelector).bind("mousedown", { 'self': this }, this.onSelectorMousedown);
};
```

And make EventHandler like that:

```
 Selector.prototype.onSelectorMousedown = function(e) {
     self = this;
     ...
 }
```

I always have self = HTMLParagraphElement instead of element that really was clicked.

Comment: I feel your code might be simplified, you already using jQuery, do not see why you use prototyping on a such trivia, they by the way not cheap. If you want to separate logic, why not use hash in a singletone pattern instead?

Comment: it's just a piece of code where I have a problem, in general, this code selected dom elements. But i have unexpected behavior, and i dont know reason for that

Comment: Okay, gotcha it is hard to judge sorry. Looks like over there `bind("mousedown", { 'self': this }` you passed custom parameter `self` to the `onSelectorMousedown`. Did you tried use just `self`, without `self=this` in latter?

Comment: If you mean e.data.self, yes i try but it also = HTMLParagraphElement

Comment: yeah, that's what I meant, looks like that without additional code or at least simplified example it is very difficult to understand what's going on.

Comment: If you specify what code you need, I'l give it to you)